# how to loop through checkboxes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm in the middle of translating a former PHP web application to ASP.Net in visual basic for the purposes of a server transfer.

What I'm trying to do is loop through a set of checkboxes to see if they are checked, and if so, add their value to a string.

From what I read, a checkbox that is set up as an HTML input instead of a ASP control can be tricky to loop through and get the value from.

Also, the checkboxes control additional groups of checkboxes, so if (for example) checkbox1 is checked, then I need to check group A of checkboxes to see which of those are checked. If checkbox 3 is checked I need to loop through group B etc...

All the checkboxes have ID's with a simple incremental naming convention: PE1, PE2, PE3 etc...

What is the best way to do this in ASP using VB? In php it was simple to loop through submitted checkboxes and just using a variable and counter to identify them:

```
var name = 'PE';
For(i=1; i<10; i++){
    checkbox = name.i;
    if(checkbox.checked){
        Blah blah. You get the point.
    }
}
```

But I'm unsure how to go about this in vb.net.

I've experimented with FindControl, but had little luck in transfering that to usable code so far.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, `FindControl` is the way to go if you want to find the `CheckBoxes` dynamically. You could also loop `parentControl.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()` with a `For Each` and check their ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest difference between looping through ASP checkboxes and HTML checkboxes is when you are checking for a type you have to use: "HtmlInputCheckbox", not "Checkbox". That took me a long time to figure out, but now the loops work just fine.

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is HtmlInputCheckBox Then
     Dim chkbox As HtmlInputCheckBox = CType(ctrl, HtmlInputCheckBox)
     If chkbox.Checked Then
     Blah
     End If
End If
```

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

If these are HTML controls and not asp.net CheckBox controls then I would do this using javscript (jQuery if that's an option).

If you insist on using the server side to do this, then you will need to add a `runat="server"` to all of your html inputs and then search for them on the server side by using [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx).  Actually now that I say it out loud, you should probably just convert them to asp.net CheckBox controls if you aren't going to use javascript.

Comment: I would do that, but since ASP controls add identifiers to the end of ID's, it's hard to manipulate them using javascript. The javascript would work if i didn't need to then store the compiled string into a database.

Comment: To reference the generated clientID you can use this method: `$("#<%= myCheckBox.ClientID %>")`  This is a good trick to remember if you are using javascript with a .net application.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to loop through ASP checkboxes than HTML checkboxes?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Is there a benefit to changing all the HTML inputs to ASP inputs to make it easier to loop through all the control? Meaning, with HTML inputs I would have to use FindControl and/or loop through all controls with type of checkbox. Is this the same route with ASP checkboxes or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying.  I guess there wouldn't be a huge advantage either way.